# Android Google Map v2 dont show map

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am testing the google map v2 on Android. I followed this [Tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.de/)

When I run the application on my mobile phone, I can not see the map. I don't no why. I don't think, that i forgot something. I have configured all the necessary things.

Here is a screenshot: http://s14.directupload.net/file/d/3130/68zcf2um_png.htm:

the logcat massages:

```
01-09 17:25:21.150: D/dalvikvm(18006): Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-09 17:25:21.455: D/dalvikvm(18006): GC_CONCURRENT freed 198K, 3% free 9458K/9735K, paused  2ms+2ms
01-09 17:25:22.075: D/dalvikvm(18006): GC_CONCURRENT freed 268K, 4% free 9635K/9991K, paused 1ms+2ms
01-09 17:25:22.600: D/dalvikvm(18006): GC_CONCURRENT freed 270K, 4% free 9830K/10183K, paused 2ms+2ms
01-09 17:25:22.765: D/dalvikvm(18006): GC_CONCURRENT freed 207K, 3% free 10154K/10439K, paused 2ms+4ms
01-09 17:25:22.835: D/SensorManager(18006): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 1
01-09 17:25:22.835: D/SensorManager(18006): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 2
01-09 17:25:22.835: D/SensorManager(18006): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 3
01-09 17:25:22.835: D/SensorManager(18006): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 4
01-09 17:25:22.835: D/SensorManager(18006): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 5
01-09 17:25:22.835: D/SensorManager(18006): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 6
01-09 17:25:22.835: D/SensorManager(18006): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 7
01-09 17:25:22.835: D/SensorManager(18006): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 8
01-09 17:25:22.835: D/SensorManager(18006): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 9
01-09 17:25:22.835: D/SensorManager(18006): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 10
01-09 17:25:22.835: D/SensorManager(18006): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 0
01-09 17:25:22.840: D/SensorManager(18006): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K3DH Acceleration Sensor delay= 20000 Listener= maps.i.a@416a4570
01-09 17:25:22.845: E/SensorManager(18006): thread start
01-09 17:25:22.845: E/SensorManager(18006): =======>>> Sensor Thread Running <<<========
01-09 17:25:22.960: D/dalvikvm(18006): GC_CONCURRENT freed 259K, 4% free 10322K/10695K, paused   2ms+2ms
01-09 17:25:23.000: D/libEGL(18006): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
01-09 17:25:23.050: D/libEGL(18006): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
01-09 17:25:23.055: D/libEGL(18006): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
01-09 17:25:23.060: D/(18006): Device driver API match
01-09 17:25:23.060: D/(18006): Device driver API version: 10
01-09 17:25:23.060: D/(18006): User space API version: 10 
01-09 17:25:23.060: D/(18006): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Fri Oct  5 16:06:50 KST  2012 
01-09 17:25:23.380: D/dalvikvm(18006): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 202K, 6% free 10336K/10887K, paused 156ms
01-09 17:25:23.405: D/dalvikvm(18006): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 154K, 6% free 10335K/10887K, paused 19ms
01-09 17:25:23.425: D/dalvikvm(18006): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 152K, 6% free 10336K/10887K, paused 16ms
01-09 17:25:23.440: D/dalvikvm(18006): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 152K, 6% free 10336K/10887K, paused 14ms
01-09 17:25:23.460: D/dalvikvm(18006): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 172K, 6% free 10337K/10887K, paused 14ms
01-09 17:25:23.475: D/dalvikvm(18006): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 152K, 6% free 10337K/10887K, paused 14ms
01-09 17:25:23.495: D/dalvikvm(18006): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 152K, 6% free 10338K/10887K, paused 14ms
01-09 17:25:23.510: D/dalvikvm(18006): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 152K, 6% free 10338K/10887K, paused 14ms
01-09 17:25:23.605: D/CLIPBOARD(18006): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
01-09 17:25:23.725: D/Sensors(18006): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
01-09 17:25:23.725: I/Sensors(18006): sendDelay --- 200000000
01-09 17:25:23.725: D/SensorManager(18006): JNI - sendDelay
01-09 17:25:23.725: I/SensorManager(18006): Set normal delay = true
01-09 17:25:23.725: D/SensorManager(18006): unregisterListener:: disable all sensors for this listener,  name = K3DH Acceleration Sensor listener = maps.i.a@416a4570
```

Here is the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapClickListener {

 final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
 GoogleMap myMap;

 TextView tvLocInfo;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  tvLocInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
  initMap();
 }

private void initMap() {

     FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
     SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
     myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();
     myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
     myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
     myMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
     myMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
     myMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

     myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
     //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
     //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
     //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

     myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this); 
}

@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
     case R.id.menu_legalnotices:
      String LicenseInfo = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(
        getApplicationContext());
      AlertDialog.Builder LicenseDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
      LicenseDialog.setTitle("Legal Notices");
      LicenseDialog.setMessage(LicenseInfo);
      LicenseDialog.show();
         return true;
     }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onResume();

  int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

  if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
     "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }else{
   GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);
  }

 }

 @Override
 public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
  tvLocInfo.setText(point.toString());
  myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
 }
   }
```

The main.xml:

```
    <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the manifest:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.googlelocatorv2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<permission 
    android:name="com.example.googlelocatorv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>

<uses-permission android:name="your_package_name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature 
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" 
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="---myKey---"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.googlelocatorv2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>         
</application>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Nothing shows on the logcat, did you get any exceptions on the device?Step by step guide for your question:

http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/?s=GPS

Comment: Double check uses-permission and API key. Post code if these are fine.

Comment: hello guys, thanks for your posts and for the willingness to help me.
@ ramesh: your link is for map v1. it works fine with map v1, but i am working now with map v2. that is a little bit different

Comment: @gustek: i ckecked my uses-permissions and api-key. i will post the code

Comment: @user1953173: i also implement [Tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.de/) site code but i still getting java.lang.NullPointerException at GoogleMap myMap=myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<permission 
android:name="com.example.googlelocatorv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>

<uses-permission android:name="your_package_name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

These need to match, in your case You need to change uses-permission to

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlelocatorv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

Comment: oh maan, you are right. didnt see that :(
i changed it, but it was still the same result. the last option was to create a new api-key and its working at once. puh.. it tooks so much time. thanks gustek. you was very helpful ;)